# Adding a small description for ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I almost spent 72 hours trying to find a way to put a small description as well as an icon in my listview. I couldn't find a way to so I thought I should ask for your help. This is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvdaysInWeek"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

And my Java looked something like this

```
    public class Schedule extends ListActivity{

            ListView daysInWeek;
            String myList[] = {"Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.schedule);
                daysInWeek = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvdaysInWeek);
                daysInWeek.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList));

            }
```

Please tell me how I can add an icon and a small description below the main text in the lisview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a custom adapter.

[This example shows you how.](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)